# Teradata 'Unable to get catalog string' error when using ODBC to connect

Tags: odbc, teradata, rhel, pyodbc, unixodbc

I am trying to reach a remote host that is running Teradata services via ODBC.
The host that I am trying to connect from is 64-bit RHEL 6.x with the following Teradata software installed:

1. bteq
2. fastexp
3. fastld
4. jmsaxsmod
5. mload
6. mqaxsmod
7. npaxsmod
8. sqlpp
9. tdodbc
10. tdwallet
11. tptbase
12. tptstream
13. tpump

When I try to connect to the remote host via Python (interactive session), I receive a 'Unable to get catalog string' error:

```
[@myhost:/path/to/scripts] ->python

Python 2.6.6 (r266:84292, Nov 21 2013, 10:50:32)

[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-4)] on linux2

Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

>>> import pyodbc

>>> pyodbc.pooling = False

>>> cn = pyodbc.connect("DRIVER={Teradata}; SERVER=12.245.67.255:1025;UID=usr;PWD=pwd", ANSI = True)

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>

pyodbc.Error: ('28000', '[28000] [Teradata][ODBC Teradata Driver] Unable to get catalog string. (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')
```

Furthermore, when I try to use isql (from the unixODBC yum package), I receive the same error

```
[@my_host:/path/to/scripts] ->isql -v proddsn

[28000][Teradata][ODBC Teradata Driver] Unable to get catalog string.

[ISQL]ERROR: Could not SQLConnect
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I **think** that message means that the Teradata driver is attempting to display an error message, but it can't find the catalog file. I think you need to set an NLSPATH environment value pointing to where your tdodbc.cat file is.  Something along these lines:

```
/opt/teradata/client/lib/odbc/%N.cat
```

That funky looking %N.cat is standard, you just need to point to the correct location.

Comment: Thanks! Everything is up-and-running as expected now.